# How to get the custom post type id in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've got "video" custom post type that will generate a shortcode to display video on posts and pages based based on its id (not the post or page id).

> [wpsv_video_shortcode id="86"]

Based on the video custom post type id, I need to fetch/get the data from wp_postmeta database to modify the video width & height with javascript using "wp_localize_script()" to pass value from the "plugin.php" to external javascript.

However, I can not get the id of that video custom post type (that appear on the post or page). I've read some references and tried `global $post; $post->ID`but it doesn't work.

Please help. Thank you

```js
function wpsv_load_scripts() {  
  global $post;
  $wpsv_save_metadata = get_post_meta($post->ID);
  $wpsv_video_width = $wpsv_save_metadata['wpsv_video_width'][0];
  $wpsv_video_height = $wpsv_save_metadata['wpsv_video_height'][0];

  wp_enqueue_script('wpsv_plugin_frontend_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/wpsv-front-end-script.js');
  wp_localize_script('wpsv_plugin_frontend_js', 'wpsv_js_value', array(
      'width' => __($wpsv_video_width, 'wpsv'),
      'height' => __($wpsv_video_height, 'wpsv'),
    )
  );
 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpsv_load_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this. There are several ways to achieve this. The most important part is to understand the PHP handle the backend and JS handle the front end. So JS can not interact with the DB directly to fetch the id, that's why wp provideo wp_localize_script() function.

The first solution is to echo the width and height on the PHP file (that I currently echo on the js file). The second solution is to pass the data to js file using hidden element :

```
<input type="hidden" id="myvar" value="'.$wpsv_video_width.'">
```

or

```
<p id="myvar" class="'.$wpsv_video_width.'" style="display:none"></p>
```

or

```
<p id="myvar" class="'.$wpsv_video_width.'" style="visibility:hidden"></p>
```